# What is the next limit equal to?

Tags: analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})=?$$
I tried amplifying the hole substraction to form the formula $$a^3-b^3$$ but didn't worked out. Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Same as $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[3]{n^3})$ . Now it's easy.

Comment: i don't get it how

Comment: Notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[3]{n^3+1} - \sqrt[3]{n^3} = 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt[3]{n^3+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt[3]{n^3}$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3}\to 0$ , multiply $\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$ with $(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n)/(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n)$ . other calculations are unnecessarily complicated

Comment: I often insert $\; \text {\;} \;$ for a little extra space after a square root because  the next symbol sometimes seems to be a little to close to the roof of the square-root symbol.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you for the advice. I will surely consider it !

Comment: A general rule is that if $M\geq 2$  and $P(x)$ is a polynomial $P(x)=x^M+ax^{M-1}+....$ of degree $M$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty} (P(x))^{1/M}-x=a/M.$

Comment: I also prefer the extra space in "$A$ is not a divisor of $B$". That is, $A\not | \; B$ instead of  $A\not | B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalized binomial theorm:

$(a+b)^k = a^k + ka^{k-1}b + \frac {k(k-1)}{2} a^{k-2}b^2 + \cdots$

$(n^2+n)^\frac 12 = n + \frac 12  - \frac {1}{8} n^{-1} + \cdots\\
(n^3+1)^\frac 13 = n + \frac 13 n^{-2} + \cdots$

Subtract one from the other and let $n$ go to infinity...

$\frac 12$

Comment: oh, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: You use a sledge-hammer to crack a nut. :)

Comment: The power series for the Generalized Binomial Theorem (for arbitrary $k,$ and $|b|<|a|$ ) was discovered by Isaac Newton, who  found it invaluable in evaluating numerical values for integrals that occur in the study of planetary motions. For example for the length of an arc of an ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}&=\sqrt[6]{(n^2+n)^3}-\sqrt[6]{(n^3+1)^2}\\&=\frac{(n^2+n)^3-(n^3+1)^2}{\sqrt[6]{(n^2+n)^3}^5+\sqrt[6]{(n^2+n)^3}^4\sqrt[6]{(n^3+1)^2}+\cdots+\sqrt[6]{(n^3+1)^2}^5}\\&=\frac{3n^5+3n^4-n^3-1}{\sqrt[6]{(n^2+n)^3}^5+\sqrt[6]{(n^2+n)^3}^4\sqrt[6]{(n^3+1)^2}+\cdots+\sqrt[6]{(n^3+1)^2}^5}.\end{align}This quotient behaves as $\dfrac{3n^5}{6n^5}$ and therefore its limit is $\dfrac12$.

Comment: I think you should have $3n^5$ in the numerator.

Comment: Why on earth was this down voted?  (+1) to neutralize

Comment: @DougM I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you. That was nice of you.

Comment: You're welcome.  I simply cannot tolerate and sit idle while a user down votes a solid answer.

Comment: @MarkViola **Two** users, in this case.

Comment: @MarkViola. Re: Down-vote. Maybe someone thought it looked too complicated.

Comment: @MarkViola I think the downvotes referred to the final result of the unedited version which was wrong

Comment: @MarkViola I was one of the downvoters - I had downvoted when this answer was incorrect, and I've now retracted it.

Comment: @B.Mehta Got to say: that's a good reason. But you could have called my attention to the error.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This was after Doug's comment.

Comment: @B.Mehta Got it. It makes sense.

Comment: @B.Mehta I would suggest that before pulling the trigger, inform the user who posts a solution that there is an error, an ambiguity in the solution, or other issue that can be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the (not so) popular standard limit $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^r-a^r} {x-a} =ra^{r-1}\tag{1}$$ The given expression (the one whose limit is to be evaluated) can be written as $$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}-\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}$$ Now we add and subtract $1 $ in the numerator and see that the expression can be written as $$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}-1}{\dfrac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}}-1}{\dfrac{1}{n^3}}$$ Next we put $x=1+(1/n),y=1+(1/n^3)$ so that $x\to 1,y\to 1$ and the expression can be written as $$\frac{x^{1/2}-1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\frac{y^{1/3}-1}{y-1}$$ and using $(1) $ the desired limit is easily seen to be $$\frac{1}{2}-0\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Paramanand. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Let $1/n=h$

$$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-\sqrt[3]{1+h^3}}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}h-\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+h^3}-1}{h^3}\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}h^2$$

For the first choose

$\sqrt{1+h}-1=u\implies h=(u+1)^2-1$

and for the second $\sqrt[3]{1+h^3}-1=v\implies h^3=(1+v)^3-1$